# Remove Indentation in Jinja Template

Tags: python, latex, jinja2, indentation, code-formatting

I'm writing a Jinja template for a LaTeX document, but I'm guessing this problem is more general to Jinja templates as a whole. The particular problem I'm having is more an aesthetical than a functional (I'm writing a LaTeX template, so my output is not indentation sensitive).

When writing Jinja templates, it might make sense to indent parts of the code to show block structure as in (whitespace shown as dots - 4 dots are one tab):

```
{% for foo in bar %}
....Outer Text
....{% for foobar in fuzbar %}
........Inner Text
........More Inner Text
........Even More Inner Text
....{% endfor }
....More Outer Text
{% endfor %}
```

Now, whitespace control allows to remove newlines of blocks of text directly before and after a block. However, I would like to have all whitespace at the beginning of indented lines removed. So the output of the example above should be:

```
Outer Text
Inner Text
More Inner Text
Even More Inner Text
More Outer Text
```

Note, that as I'm writing a LaTeX template, regular lines might start with `\t` as in `\textwidth`. I would like to have a solution, that deals both with whitespaces and tabs at line beginnings. Other code formatting solutions would also be appreciated if they work better with Jinja and still allow to visually grasp logical blocks.

The only idea I have so far is using only `space` at the beginning of each line instead of multiple `tabs` and do a linewise

`lstrip(' ')`

in python.

Comment: I just realized this might be a tabs vs. spaces question.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Yes, I basically did what I suggested in my last sentence. Replaced all tabs with spaces and do a linewise `lstrip(' ')`